# Any conflicts between UI-Bootstrap and Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Are there any conflicts between [Angular UI-Bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages) and [Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)?

I am trying to avoid using jQuery-UI with AngularJS if a more Angular-friendly UI package is available. I already started with Twitter Bootstrap, so I do not wish to unload Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no conflicts. Especially since [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is dependent on Twitter Bootstrap.

From the linked docs:

> This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only **required dependencies** are:
>
> AngularJS (requires AngularJS 1.3.x, tested with 1.3.13). 0.12.0 is the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.2.x.
>
> **Bootstrap CSS** (tested with version 3.1.1). This version of the library (0.13.0) works only with Bootstrap CSS in version 3.x. 0.8.0 is the last version of this library that supports Bootstrap CSS in version 2.3.x.

Comment: So the UI-Bootstrap library depends upon twitter Bootstrap CSS.  But not the JavaScript.  Could there be a conflict with the JavaScript?

Comment: I have both included in a project with no issue. In fact, with some of the stuff I've done I had to add the Bootstrap JS lib since I was writing custom directives. You should be fine with just the ui-bootstrap lib, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going all in on Angular then stick with either [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) or [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), do not mix it with Twitter Bootstrap JS library. Both of the Angular projects mentioned utilize the Bootstrap CSS, but they completely replace the Bootstrap JS library, with pretty much all functionality included.

Apart from the unnecessary bloat to load both libraries, you'll end up with issues integrating the Bootstrap JS library with Angular for stuff like model binding.

Comment: Ok, you inspired me to ditch the Bootstrap js and take the AngularStrap plunge.  AngularStrap seems to be more active than Angular UI Bootstrap (although both are active)

Comment: @steampowered That is my opinion as well. I started off with Angular UI, and have been frustrated on occasion on their slow pace of updating stuff. Especially going from Angular 1.2 to 1.3 If I were to start over I would go the AngularStrap route instead.